# Integrating a function with the spherical Bessel function of the first kind

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, special-functions

I want to integrate a function with the spherical Bessel function of the first kind from $0$ to $\infty$. I tried in many different ways, but didn't get any appropriate answer; if anyone can help me I am very thankful.

```
psi[n_?NumericQ, x_?NumericQ] := x SphericalBesselJ[n, x];

Result = NIntegrate[psi[n, x], {x, 0, ∞}, MaxRecursion -> 20, 
                      PrecisionGoal -> 10, AccuracyGoal -> 15]
```

Comment: Note that $x j_n(x) \sim\cos \left(\frac{\pi}{2}(n+1)-x\right)$ as $x\rightarrow\infty$, so these integrals don't converge for any real values of $n$. If you plot the integrand, you'll see why.

Comment: If you multiply the integrand by `Exp[-a x]`, integrate, and take the limit as `a -> 0`, you can obtain `Binomial[n - 1/2, n - 1]/2` for odd `n` and `1/Binomial[n - 3/2, n - 1]` for even `n` (assuming `n` is a nonnegative integer). Caveat: I did this with `Integrate`, which gave me an answer in terms of `Hypergeometric2F1Regularized`, but I haven't checked for correctness/reasonableness.

Answer (score 2):

Let me formalize Michael's proposal in the comments. What he is suggesting is that you take the Laplace transform of your integrand, and then take the limit of that transform at $0$ (i.e., evaluating the divergent oscillatory integral [in the Abel sense](https://dlmf.nist.gov/1.15.E30)).

Thus:

```
LaplaceTransform[x SphericalBesselJ[n, x] // FunctionExpand, x, h] // FullSimplify
   2^(-1 - n) h^(-2 - n) Sqrt[π] Gamma[2 + n]
   Hypergeometric2F1Regularized[(2 + n)/2, (3 + n)/2, 3/2 + n, -1/h^2]
```

Unfortunately, attempting to take the limit of this as $h\to0$ does not yield anything useful, so we take a circuitous route.

The idea is to convert the expression to a [Meijer $G$-function](https://dlmf.nist.gov/16.17) and hope the result is a bit more amenable.

Using `MeijerGReduce[]` on the hypergeometric function, we have

```
MeijerGReduce[Hypergeometric2F1Regularized[(2 + n)/2, (3 + n)/2, 3/2 + n, -z], z]
   MeijerG[{{-n/2, -1/2 - n/2}, {}}, {{0}, {-1/2 - n}}, z]/
   (Gamma[(2 + n)/2] Gamma[(3 + n)/2])
```

(I have suppressed the inactivated form for readability in the previous and in all subsequent outputs.)

Combining the prefactors of this result with the prefactors of the bigger expression, we have

```
2^(-1 - n) h^(-2 - n) Sqrt[π] Gamma[2 + n]/(Gamma[(2 + n)/2] Gamma[(3 + n)/2])
// FullSimplify
   h^(-2 - n)
```

so our function under consideration is now

```
h^(-2 - n) MeijerG[{{-n/2, -1/2 - n/2}, {}}, {{0}, {-1/2 - n}}, 1/h^2]
```

We now employ a few identities satisfied by the $G$ function. First, we use the ["absorption identity"](https://dlmf.nist.gov/16.19.E2), which yields

```
Inactive[MeijerG][{{-n/2, -1/2 - n/2}, {}} + (n + 2)/2,
                  {{0}, {-1/2 - n}} + (n + 2)/2, 1/h^2] // Simplify
   MeijerG[{{1, 1/2}, {}}, {{1 + n/2}, {1/2 - n/2}}, 1/h^2]
```

Finally, employing the ["flip identity"](https://dlmf.nist.gov/16.19.E1) gives

```
Inactive[MeijerG][1 - {{1 + n/2}, {1/2 - n/2}}, 1 - {{1, 1/2}, {}}, h^2] // Simplify
   MeijerG[{{-n/2}, {(1 + n)/2}}, {{0, 1/2}, {}}, h^2]
```

And now, we let `h -> 0`:

```
 Activate[% /. h -> 0]
   (Sqrt[π] Gamma[1 + n/2])/Gamma[(1 + n)/2]
```

or alternatively, `n/2 Beta[1/2, n/2]`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this to see what is going on.  Mathematica can get the indefinite integral.

```
intp = Integrate[x SphericalBesselJ[n, x], x]
(*Sqrt[Pi] 2^(-n - 2) x^(n + 2)Gamma[n/2 + 1]
 HypergeometricPFQRegularized[{n/2 + 1}, {n + 3/2, n/2 + 2}, -(x^2/4)]*)
```

I know you don't specify `n` to be an integer, but we can look at the first 5 integers for `n`, just to get a look.

```
tab = Table[intp, {n, 5}];
```

At `x = Infinity`

```
Limit[tab, x -> Infinity] // N
(*{Interval[{0.570796,2.5708}],Interval[{1.,3.}],Interval[{1.35619,3.35619}],Interval[{1.66667,3.66667}],Interval[{1.94524,3.94524}]}*)
```

The oscillation of the trig functions give a value range at `Infinity`.

At `x = 0`, `Limit[tab, x -> 0]` yields `0` for the 5 cases.

In many cases Mathematica fails to produce a result with `NIntegrate`, but can produce results with `Integrate`, so it is wise to check out the other possibility when one fails.

Answer (score 1):

Integral **regularization** in simpler **way**:

```
f=Integrate[ x^-e*SphericalBesselJ[n, x], {x, 0, ∞}, 
  Assumptions -> {e >= 0, n > 0, n ∈ Integers}][[1]]

(*(2^(-1 - e) Sqrt[π] Gamma[1/2 (1 - e + n)])/Gamma[1/2 (2 + e + n)]*)

Limit[f, e -> -1]

(* (Sqrt[π] Gamma[(2 + n)/2])/Gamma[(1 + n)/2] *)
```

> $\frac{\sqrt{\pi } \Gamma \left(\frac{n+2}{2}\right)}{\Gamma \left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right)}$

Comment: Oh, you took the Borel route. :D